# File name/path of javax.xml.transform.Source object

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an input supplier that extends Source: `InputSupplier<? extends Source> supplier` and I would like to get the file name (and path) of the source.

Currently the Source is always a StreamSource, so I don't know if that makes it more or less challenging.

Comment: @home What other code could I show?

Comment: The source does not necessarily refer to a file or path... it could just be a stream from a remote location. So it all depends on your code (the way you create the source).

Comment: You can't... What are you trying to do that means you want to get the file name / path?

Answer (score 1):

StreamSource.getSystemId returns the system identifier that was set with setSystemId, or null if setSystemId was not called. Examples:

```
System.out.println(new StreamSource(new File("1.xml")).getSystemId());
System.out.println(new StreamSource(new FileReader("1.xml")).getSystemId());
System.out.println(new StreamSource(new FileReader("1.xml"), "d://workspace/x/1.xml").getSystemId());
```

prints

```
file:/D:/workspace1/x/1.xml
null
d://workspace/x/1.xml
```

So it depends on how StreamSource was created.